# Wordpress: Image + Text widget wanted

Tags: wordpress, image, text, widget

I’m looking for the widget for the sidebar which will be able to make “nice boxes”. I’m not sure how to properly name it, please just look at screenshot (I’m talking about this
[purple “box”](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZjMz.jpg)).
What do I need from this widget:

- Ability to set background image
- Rounded corners for widget
- Ability to put text of any size and to use any font I want

Would be nice, but not necessarily:

- Ability to put nifty buttons on it
- Set opacity of background image

And, by the way, tell me please what is the correct name for such “boxes”?

Thank you!

Comment: According to the Stack Overflow Help section on [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  Although you do ask a legitimate question at the end, I think the takeaway from this post is that you are looking for some sort of "library" or tutorial to get this done.  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Use this plugin. It will let you build a widget with text and images.
Widget Content Blocks
Network Activate | Delete
Adds a WYSIWYG Widget with a rich text editor and media upload functions.

Version 2.3.8 | By Danny van Kooten | View details | Security Check